# public key authentication without authorized_keys file

Tags: ssh, authentication, openssh

I have a lot of ssh public key logins on a Linux server, e.g.:

```
Jul 25 11:41:01 host sshd[24594]: Accepted publickey for root from xxx.xxx.xx.xx port 33374 ssh2
```

This is strange for me since there's no `authorized_keys` file in the `/root/.ssh` directory. The `AuthorizedKeysFile` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has the default value of `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I wonder how is it possible to login to the server using public key authentication?

Comment: Do you know if `sshd_config` has been modified since `sshd` was last restarted?

Comment: @Joel: yep, I've tried restarting the `sshd` service.

Comment: What else is inside /root/.ssh?  Is there for instance an authorized_keys2 file?   If you can restart sshd, you can restart it with verbose logging.  Examine what files it looks at during one of these episodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out what's going on. The messages are coming to the server from remote hosts via UDP. I didn't notice the host field changing at first, my mistake.

BTW, actually there *is* a possibility to login using public key authentication with no `authorized_keys` file involved. RedHat (and variants) have a supported patch for OpenSSH that adds the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` and `AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs` options. The patch has been merged upstream in [OpenSSH 6.2](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.2). To quote from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

> **AuthorizedKeysCommand**
>
> Specifies a program to be used for lookup of the user's public keys.
>   The program will be invoked with its first argument the name of the
>   user being authorized, and should produce on standard output
>   AuthorizedKeys lines (see AUTHORIZED_KEYS in sshd(8)). By default (or
>   when set to the empty string) there is no AuthorizedKeysCommand run.
>   If the AuthorizedKeysCommand does not successfully authorize the user,
>   authorization falls through to the AuthorizedKeysFile. Note that this
>   option has an effect only with PubkeyAuthentication turned on.
>
> **AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs**
>
> Specifies the user under whose account the AuthorizedKeysCommand is
>   run. Empty string (the default value) means the user being authorized
>   is used.